# Soft RAID and dual boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, dmraid

My motherboard support Fake Raid. Can I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 and both running on Raid (Stripe)? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've seen this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

In short, you could try to partition the raid within the BIOS setup and install Ubuntu using the Alternate CD.

If you're having trouble getting the system to boot up after installing, this might help: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic153346.html